# Wipe out windows 8 just leave OpenSuse

Tags: windows, opensuse

I was trying to install OpenSuse 13.1 on a Windows 8 pre-installed PC.
Using the default installation does not go to GRUB loader but loading windows directly instead. While trying different things I have also removed all windows related partitions and now it only goes to windows repair.

Isn’t there a way to wipe out windows and just install OpenSuse 13.1? I am **not** interested in dual booting

Comment: How about `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX` to wipe the whole disk and start fresh? If you really don't care about what happens to Windows, surely this is fine?

Comment: As an FYI, new version of OpenSuSE in a month or so.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [UEFI entry](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:UEFI) on the openSUSE wiki, and for example [openSUSE Forums](http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/492719-recover-dual-boot-after-install-windows-8-1) for instructions how to install the bootloader shim. Also see the [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373555/opensuse-shim-certificate-for-uefi-secure-boot).

Since you are not interested in dual booting, you might also want look for a way to add more keys to the UEFI on your computer, so that you can get rid of the Microsoft bootloader entirely.

Another option is turning SecureBoot off or even switch to legacy MBR-based booting.

To entirely remove windows, all you need to do is to clean the EFI partition. However, I would strongly suggest archiving it (and the recovery partition) in case you needed to restore it when things go wrong. The easiest way would be putting the hard drive into another computer (or booting a live CD) and saving:

1. the GPT
2. the EFI partition
3. the Windows recovery partition

For GPT yo ucan use `parted` or `gdisk` (sometimes also known as `gptfdisk`), the latter two are best cloned by `dd`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, on some computers, the UEFI (which I assume you have, based on that behavior) or the shipped Windows 8 installation, is configured in a way that does not permit you to install anything next to or instead of Windows 8, and, if you managed to wipe out Windows 8, just starts off a recovery partition.

The solution, according to [this german forum post](http://www.opensuse-forum.de/allgemeines/vor-der-installation/9839-gel%C3%B6st-suse-13-1-und-uefi/), can be re-installing Windows 8 using a recovery disk. Then, the Linux installation should be capable of successfully creating the boot manager entry.